# Rendering in Shiny: red error before reactive data loads

Tags: shiny, rendering, reactive

I am sure there is a function out there that will let me wait to render my Echarts4R output once my pickers & reactive data have loaded, as to mitigate the [ugly red warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5FhR.png)  until they do! Once the reactive data is loaded, I get a nice output [as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6JQ5.png). It would be even better to have a little loading symbol or something while they load. It only takes about a second to load, though, so that isnt imperative.

Here are some example code snippets.
The UI for the graphic:

```
box(width = 12, title = "Total Escalated Project Costs by Calendar Year", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, status = "primary"
                                      ,echarts4rOutput("initiative_cashflow")
```

And the server for the graphic:

```
  output$Breakdown_by_Project <- renderEcharts4r({
breakdown_by_project_data <- init_data() %>%
  group_by(Project) %>%
  summarise(total_project_cost = sum(`Escalated Project Cost`))%>%
  select(Project, total_project_cost)%>%
  e_charts(Project)%>%
  e_pie(total_project_cost, radius = c("50%", "70%"))%>%
  e_legend(show = FALSE) %>%
  e_tooltip()})
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4322318) will help us to help you. Also, check the `shiny::req` function, it could help you.

Comment: @Geovany I will look into shiny::req. In the meantime, I have added two snippets of code, hope that helps! Thank you.

Comment: @Geovany req solved the issue! Thanks!